# image to flash moto 4g play

Tags: rom-flashing

I'm trying to remove the anoying amazon malware on my moto G.  I tried following these instructions: http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4/development/moto-g-4th-gen-how-to-remove-amazon-t3416587 but without success.  both the RSDLight and non-RSDLight approaches fail.  I get a message saying that the image test failed.

I assume the problem is that i'm using an image for a moto 4g instead of a moto 4g play.  Where could I get an image to flash my phone with for a moto 4G play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon and Moto patched the methods used to remove advertising, I have to assume they did it on the G4 Play as well, meaning there are no known ways to remove the advertising on the current firmware for the G4 or G4 Play, except by going to Your Devices on Amazon and pay the $50 to remove the advertising. If you are a long time Prime customer, calling and complaining to customer service that the advertising is too bright and annoying has resulting in getting it removed free of charge for some people (yet not others).